# Function does not end after return placed in condition

Tags: c++

Here is Node definition:

```
Node::Node(int value, Node* left, Node* right) {
   this->value = value;
   this->left = left;
   this->right = right;
}

int Node::getValue() const {
   return value;
}

Node* Node::getLeft() const {
   return left;
}

Node* Node::getRight() const {
   return right;
}
```

And here function contains:

```
static bool contains(const Node& root, int value)
{
   cout << "Root value: " << root.getValue() << endl;
   if(root.getValue() == value)
   {
      cout << "You entered." << endl;
      return true;
   }
   else if(root.getLeft() != NULL)
   {
      cout << "Left tree: " << endl;
      contains(*(root.getLeft()), value);
   }
   else if(root.getRight() != NULL)
   {
      cout << "Right tree: " << endl;
      contains(*(root.getRight()), value);
   }

   cout << "End" << endl;
   return false;
}
```

Now I use this function:

```
Node n1(1, NULL, NULL);
Node n3(3, NULL, NULL);
Node n2(2, &n1, &n3);

cout << "Contains? " << contains(n2, 1) << endl;
```

This 1 value is in left subtree. It displays "You entered." and anyway goes to the end of function displaying 0 as a result. Why it doesn't display 1(true)? What did I miss?

Comment: You're missing a couple of crucial `return` keywords, e.g. `contains(*(root.getLeft()), value);` should be: `return contains(*(root.getLeft()), value);`

Comment: Is this really an offtopic to this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some return statements.

```
cout << "Root value: " << root.getValue() << endl;

if(root.getValue() == value)
{
    cout << "You entered." << endl;
    return true;
}
else if(root.getLeft() != NULL)
{
    cout << "Left tree: " << endl;
    contains(*(root.getLeft()), value); // no return here 
}
else if(root.getRight() != NULL)
{
    cout << "Right tree: " << endl;
    contains(*(root.getRight()), value); // and no return here
}

cout << "End" << endl;
return false;
```

It checks whether the tree contains the value somewhere but nether carries the result to the outside world. Change it to

```
if (root.getValue() == value)
{
    cout << "You entered." << endl;
    return true;
}
auto left = root.getLeft();
if (left)
{
   cout << "Checking Left tree: " << endl;
   if (contains(*left, value))
        return true;
}
auto right = root.getRight();
if (right)
{
   cout << "Checking Right tree: " << endl;
   if (contains(*right, value))
        return true;
}

cout << "End" << endl;
return false;
```

And it should work.

Comment: this will look in the left subtree if it exists, and skip the right if it is not found in the left

Comment: Yes, I see it now. I tested it for 3 value and it won't work.

Comment: @sp2danny Thank you for editing it. I was just a thew moments to slow to correct it my self ;-)